# How do I send Control Alt Delete from a Mac to a remote Windows PC

Tags: macos, keyboard, remote-desktop

I am trying to log into my PC at work from my Mac. It requires <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd> key combination to login.

How do I do it from my Mac?

Comment: if you are using Microsoft Remote Desktop it is Ctrl-Alt-Insert, you may need a PC keyboard to do that particular combination.

Comment: @Claudia, you should edit this question to overtly state which software on MacOS that you were using to remote-desktop into Windows at work.  A moderator closed this question simply due to the fact that it has multiple valid answers for various different remote desktop software packages.  Just because it is closed doesn't mean that it needs to remain in that state forever.  You can resurrect it by performing the edits requested.  SO is seeking to build a body of the 1 canonical answer for each topic.  As stated in question, we don't know what the exact topic is, hence the closure.

Answer (score 17):

With MS Remote Desktop Connection, fn+Ctrl+Alt+Del works fine.

Comment: With which Remote Access application?

Comment: @nohillside - I presume MS RDC, for short keyboards without a true Delete key Fn/Backspace == 'true'  Delete. On an extended keyboard, just Ctrl/Opt/Delete works just fine.

Comment: @nohillside MS Remote Desktop Connection

Answer (score 5):

Depends on how you're controlling the remote PC. On most remote control software, you select "Ctrl-Alt-Del" from the menu to send the command to the remote PC.

The option key on the mac keyboard is also labeled alt and there is usually a delete key, too on larger / external keyboards.

Answer (score 5):

Connect using Microsoft Remote Desktop. To send the "Control + Alt + Delete" in Windows, press <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>del</kbd> on your Mac keyboard. This works for macOS Big Sur

Comment: This was helpful. I'm using a [PC keyboard](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/keyboard-mappings-using-a-pc-keyboard-on-a-macintosh-d4fd87ca-8762-30ee-fcde-08ffe95faea3) so for me it was "Ctrl + Alt + Backspace"

Answer (score 3):

Following keyboard shortcut worked for me:

<kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>delete</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

If using MacOS Screen Sharing then
<kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>delete</kbd>
works for me.

More detail: the target Windows computer has VNC server (or equivalent) running, which allows MacOS Screen Sharing app to connect using finder to connect to vnc://192.168.1.42 by IP address to windows.

Comment: Would you elaborate how you use screen sharing to connect to windows? Looks like a great answer with an edit on how you set this up compared to the other answer saying this combination works

Comment: I added a little detail – is that what you had in mind?

Comment: Looks nice. I added the connect to - knowing you use the os provided screen sharing app and VNC server on windows is key and helpful. Thanks !